# SqlDataAdapter.Update: Are there SQL version requirements?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know there are questions like this already, but I've combined all the common code to the answers and still am getting no success, so here I am.

Here's the deal.  I have a block of code using SqlDataAdapter.Update to insert new rows into an existing table...

```
string command = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
// Initialize connection
if (oConn == null)
{
    oConn = new SqlConnection(mainConnStr);
}

sCmd = new SqlCommand(command, oConn);
sCmd.CommandText = command;
SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sCmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

oConn.Open();
sDA.Fill(ds, tableName);
oConn.Close();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[tableName];

//Add each row.
for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.ImportRow(queryResult.Rows[i]);
}
// Handle the command building for the table update.
SqlCommandBuilder sCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(sDA);

oConn.Open();
sDA.Update(ds, tableName);
oConn.Close();
```

As mentioned, this works fine.  However, if I try very similar code with a two-column test table (testInt, an int non-null; and testSTring, a varchar(50), null-allowed)...

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection = /* Build connection */

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE 0 = 1";
    SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    sDA.Fill(dataSet);
    conn.Close();

    DataRow newRow = dataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
    newRow["testInt"] = 12;

    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sDA);
    conn.Open();
    sDA.Update(dataSet);
    conn.Close();
}
```

This code does nothing, and I can't figure out what in the world the difference is.  (I should note that I've also tried using ImportRow instead of the NewRow technique.) Even when I try this block of code with the same tables as the first block (the working block), it still won't update the data.

Therefore, my question is: What fine details must be accounted for when using SqlDataAdapter.Update?

Thanks.

-F

Comment: Perhaps you need to return some data before you can update it?

Comment: I am assuming this is just sample code and not how you have written the real thing, but just as a heads up, `SqlCommandBuilde, `DataSet`, `DataTable`, and your `SqlConnection` all implement `IDisposable` and should have their `Dispose()` method called.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the row to the DataSet

```
DataRow newRow = dataSet.Tables[0].NewRow(); // this doesn't add a new row to the data set
dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow); // you have to call this after
```

Comment: See the sample for [NewRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) on MSDN